# Problem when using duplicate AssociationField fields of the same EasyAdmin entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5, easyadmin, easyadmin3

EasyAdmin 4
There is an M2M relationship between Product and AttributeValue.
There can be thousands of rows in AttributeValue, and to make it easier to create/edit products, you need to divide the values by attribute, which is actually done through QueryBuilder, but there is a problem when using duplicate AssociationField ('AttributeValues'). When editing or creating an object, only the (last) "Property #2" field is displayed.
How to fix it?

```
AssociationField::new('attributeValues', 'Property #1')
->setQueryBuilder(function(QueryBuilder $qb) {
return $qb->andWhere('entity.attribute = 5');
}),

AssociationField::new('attributeValues', 'Property #2')
->setQueryBuilder(function(QueryBuilder $qb){
return $qb->andWhere('entity.attribute = 1');
}),
```

Comment: It is simply impossible (on Symfony and therefore Easyadmin) to render an attribute twice in a form (here `attributeValues`).  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @vinceAmstoutz  !  
**AttributeValues** stores the values of all product properties and there can be a very large number of them.
For the convenience of creating/editing products, I would like to divide the values into property (**entity.attribute**) categories.

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz  
Javier Eguiluz wrote in his response to Github ([link](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3751#issuecomment-860900162)) that it is possible to use two absolutely identical fields. Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: At no point in any case does it provide a functional solution. Sorry but for me isn't possible so I can tell you how you can do that.

Comment: Well done man :) !